# How to optimize CPU and RAM usage on a UIView which uses `drawInRect:blendMode:`?

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization, uiview, uibezierpath

I'm developing a drawing app which lets user to draw one UIBezierpath just once over an image which has been drawn in the UIView by `drawInRect:blendMode` in `drawRect` method and it's uses over 80% of CPU and 55MB of RAM and when I traced it down in the time profiler, it was `drawInRect:blendMode` method that was causing most of the CPU usage. I have already done few optimizations but what further optimizations can I do for both drawing the UIImage which is being drawn using `[image drawInRect:Rect];` and also for the UIBezierpath which user draws on top of it?
Thanks in advance.

```
@interface InsideView(){
    CGRect imageRect;
    CGRect targetBounds;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *strokes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage * img;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBezierPath *drawingPath;
@end

@implementation InsideView

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    targetBounds = self.layer.bounds;
    imageRect = AVMakeRectWithAspectRatioInsideRect(self.img.size,targetBounds);
    [self.img drawInRect:imageRect];

    for (int i=0; i < [self.strokes count]; i++) {
         UIBezierPath* tmp = (UIBezierPath*)[self.strokes  objectAtIndex:i];
         [[UIColor whiteColor] setStroke];
         [tmp stroke];
    }
}
- (CGRect)segmentBoundsFrom:(CGPoint)point1 to:(CGPoint)point2
{
    CGRect dirtyPoint1 = CGRectMake(point1.x-10, point1.y-10, 50, 50);
    CGRect dirtyPoint2 = CGRectMake(point2.x-10, point2.y-10, 50, 50);
    return CGRectUnion(dirtyPoint1, dirtyPoint2);
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    self.drawingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    self.drawingPath.lineWidth = 10;
    self.drawingPath.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound;
    self.drawingPath.lineJoinStyle = kCGLineJoinRound;
    [self.drawingPath moveToPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]];
    [self.strokes addObject:self.drawingPath];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    //Dirty Rect Calculations
    CGPoint prevPoint = CGPathGetCurrentPoint(self.drawingPath.CGPath);
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    CGRect dirty = [self segmentBoundsFrom:prevPoint to:point];

    [[self.strokes lastObject] addLineToPoint:point];
    [self setNeedsDisplayInRect:dirty];
}
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [[self.strokes lastObject] addLineToPoint:[[touches anyObject] locationInView:self]];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: I hope you are not making the mistake of redrawing the whole path every time a little is added to it... Did you watch the WWDC videos from this year and last year on this very topic? Very helpful if you're trying to write a "sketch" app.

Comment: I'm redrawing only the dirty rect which is being added to the rest of the path in touchesMoved method by using `[self setNeedsDisplayInRect:dirty];`. Am I doing it wrong? I mean the bezierpath gets drawn really really fast with no lags at all, I just wanna know if there's still a way to reduce the cpu usage? and It's not a sketch app since I mentioned above, only one uibezierpath gets drawn once on top of an image. Thanks :) @matt